# xp_cmdshell SQL SERVER 2012:¿Cómo se pueden imprimir caracteres "< >"?

Tags: sql, shell, cmd

Qué tal. 
Aclaro que soy un tanto novato en SQL y plenamente nuevo en el ámbito del cmdshell.
Básicamente busco depositar un archivo estructurado cada 20 mins, en una carpeta compartida para otro servidor. Planeo hacerlo a través de un JOB.
El query con la información estructurada lo tengo listo, sin embargo, el archivo necesita comenzar con un encabezado " <0600 textotexto... > " 
Viendo algunos ejemplos pude depositar el archivo, pero cuando agrego el caracter " <  > ", despliega un error.

Éste es mi código a manera de ejemplo:

```
declare @Text as nvarchar(150)  declare @Cmd as nvarchar(100)  set    @Text = '<0600 /SERIAL= ....>'  set @Cmd ='echo ' +  @Text + ' > C:\Test.txt'  execute ..xp_CmdShell  @Cmd
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer, para que el archivo se guarde con el mayor o menor que (<  >), en su estructura?

Saludos.

Comment: ¿Qué error te envía exactamente?

Comment: The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Cuando borro esos caracteres, se crea el archivo sin problemas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me temo que no podrás crear el archivo de la forma en que lo deseas, dado que los caracteres especiales `>` y `>>` forman parte de la sintaxis en el manejo de archivos:

`use 'echo " -- Text ">'` se utiliza para la creación de un archivo

`use 'echo " -- Text ">>'` se utiliza para agregar texto a un archivo existente

Por lo tanto se deben escapar con `^`

```
DECLARE @Text AS NVARCHAR(150)
declare @Cmd AS NVARCHAR(100)  
SET @Text = '^<0600 /SERIAL= ....^>'  
SET @Cmd ='echo ' +  @Text + ' > ' + 'C:\Test.txt'  
EXECUTE ..xp_CmdShell  @Cmd
```

Comment: Lo he intentado con SET @Text = '^<0600 /SERIAL= ....^>'   y funciona excelente. Muchas gracias!

Comment: De nada amigo :)